# From the perspective of an ASP.Net web form, can the Request.UserHostAddress be trusted?

Tags: asp.net, client

I have a web form that needs to act differently if the request to that form came from an internal network address or from a public IP address.  I'm trying within my web form to determine if the request is from an internal network IP.  Can I reliably do this, or can clients fake their source IP?  Can I trust the information contained in Request.UserHostAddress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't unfortunately.  It's pretty trivial to construct an HTTP request with spoofed headers.

Answer (score 1):

IP Spoofing is basically possible: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Spoofing) but has limited use (as far as I understand, it is very hard to actually *pull* any data that way)

Best thing would of course be to route/restrict traffic on firewall or proxy level (establish a rule that allows local traffic only going to your site) to create maximum security.

Comment: Your suggestion would be ideal, except that (if I understand your meaning properly) as impled in the OP the website must accept public requests, as it is a public website.