# how to block certain ip's (users) to access my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

anybody knows of blocking certain users (by IP) from accessing your website (website on asp.net mvc).

**EDIT:**
I know that web-servers can do this as well, but I need this at the application level

Comment: This is best done via server configuration rather than programming, voting to move to http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Yes, it may be "best" done on the server, but sometimes moderation tools cannot set server configurations and you need your application to handle redirecting blocked users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to do this in the web server.

However, if you want to do it in code, you can handle the `Application.BeginRequest` event, check `Request.UserHostAddress`, and call `Response.End`.

Comment: Please note IPs are easily spoofed.

Comment: @Nix: Not in this scenario, I believe. Before ASP.NET app gets a request a valid HTTP session must be initiated, and before that a TCP handshake must be complete. This won't happen with a spoofed IP.

Comment: It is possible...  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835343/from-the-perspective-of-an-asp-net-web-form-can-the-request-userhostaddress-be-t)[Spoofing]

Answer (score 1):

IIS allows you to specify IP-based block lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it at the application level you can get the users IP from Request.UserHostAddress and then do a redirect to wherever you want them to go if their IP is in a list you have saved.